# How should I use Backbone with REST via AWS?

Tags: rest, backbone.js, amazon-web-services

I'd like to start practicing JS server-based stuff in a real-world environment (not localhost) and AWS seems to be the most economical way to do this. And I'd like to start by using Backbone in conjunction with REST.

If I do this, is REST out-of-the-box ready on AWS and it's just a matter of throwing my Backbone code on the server?  Or is it a matter of configuring the REST API on AWS?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: I think Backbone.js is designed for use on the client-side, not server-side. Also, note that in practice "REST" really just means "HTTP", so as long as you're running a web server, you're doing REST.

Comment: Hi Paul.  Thanks for responding! Yea, Backbone was created to work on the client side but it can  interact with the server to pull down data. I have a low-level plan with Media Temple, who says that this plan doesn't support REST.

Comment: Right, when you said "throwing my Backbone code on the server" it sounded like you wanted to run Backbone on the server. I think I understand you better now: you want to write some JavaScript, using Backbone, that gets data from the server, and you want to know if AWS is suitable to use as a server. Which AWS service are you looking at using? EC2? Which Media Temple service didn't support REST?

Comment: Yes, you are correct...sorry that I wasn't clear. I have the a gridserver deal with MT.  RE: which AWS, I THINK that I need EC2 for Backbone server stuff. But I'm still reading up on their services but am not sure which one is best for me.

Comment: That's alright, it's not easy to be clear when you're learning a new area. I can't find any reference to Media Temple's Grid Server not supporting REST. All that Backbone.js will do in terms of communicating with the server is send HTTP requests to URLs hosted on the server, just like your web browser does. (That's what a REST API is: HTTP calls.) Any web server will be fine for this, be it Media Temple's Grid Server, AWS EC2, or anything else.

Comment: Got it...looks like the MT guy I spoke to made an error.  Thanks for clarifying things for m,e Paul.  It's indeed appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicated, web applications are broken up in to two parts, the client and the server, and Backbone is an exclusively a client-side library ...

... well, almost.  There is a server-side Javascript web framework called Node.js, and if you really wanted you could use Backbone on it.  Alternatively you could run a more traditional server-side language/framework like Ruby/Rails, Python/Django, etc.  If you are using AWS's EC2 service you basically get your own computer to do what you want with, and you can use Node, Django, or whatever else to write a REST-ful webservice that your client-side code can use.

Comment: Thx machineghost.  So unlike Rackspace where you have to install the entire application stack yourself, AWS comes ready to use RESTful?  i.e., you don't have anything to run the RESTful APIs, you just have to start writing them?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if you understand what a an API (REST-ful or otherise). API means Application Programming Interface, and as the name would imply you absolutely do need an "application" of some sort before you can have an API. As I mentioned, you can build that application with Node.js (if you want to use JS) or Django (Python) or Rails (Ruby) or any other language really, because AWS essentially gives you your own Unix box to do whatever you want with. But again, you need an application before you can have an API; there is no webhost in the world that can change that.

Comment: No, I understand what an API is...what I'm trying to clarify is, how much work is required to get it working on AWS. For example: I was thinking about going the Rackspace route with this at first, but that would require building the application stack myself, which I could work through but don't know how to do.  I was wondering if AWS allows me to skip that step, and it appears that it does.

Comment: Please understand, I'm not trying to insult you, but your language suggests you're not understanding, so I'll try to clarify. The "application stack" that you're referring to is the application that runs your site; it's what I meant when I wrote "you can build that application with Node.js (if you want to use JS) or Django (Python) or Rails (Ruby) or any other language". But neither Rackspace, AWS nor any other host in existence can let you "skip that step". To have a web application at all (ie. a site with an API) you must have your own "application stack"; no one can make it for you.

Comment: (Unless you *just* want access to a database and don't want any logic whatsoever, including no user authentication ... in which case something like Apache's CouchDB or any similar DB with http-based access might work for you.)